# Mysql return multiple rows, only need 1

Tags: mysql

How can I get just one result from multiple in MySQL?

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(data, INTERVAL(-WEEKDAY(data)) DAY) AS D 
FROM Done
GROUP BY D
```

It gives me "2017-08-07" and "2017-08-14" and I need them both, but one at the start and the other at the end. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you paste additional information:
- What does your schema look like?
- What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: That it shows me the data on Monday and the data in friday, in "data" there are things done on monday-friday and the dates on every day

Comment: Paste the whole schema, so that everyone can see. And why is the column named data and not date or something? It is not very good to name your columns `data`, because everything in a database is data :)

Comment: It is named Date in german, didn't want you guys to confuse it with Date(), lol

Comment: Avoid using non-English names for columns, table names, variables and everything like that in programming.

Answer (score 0):

The result from the query is called result set in terms of database.
So, your result set contains 2 rows, or in other words you can say that there are 2 results in the result set from this query.

In fact you have them separate - each on its own row in the result set.
When fetching the result in the programming language you are using, you will receive them as a collection or array.

Then, you can get the first and the second element of that collection/array and print them as desired.

Comment: I'm using php, tried separating them but it never worked properly

Comment: If `$result` is the result set, `$result[0]` will return the first row of the result set, and `$result[1]` will return the second row of the result set.

Comment: $result[0] gives 22, $resut[1] gives 00, $result[2] gives 11 and $result[3] gives 77

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_1;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl_1
AS
SELECT 
    DATE_ADD(data, INTERVAL(-WEEKDAY(data)) DAY) AS D,@row_num:=@row_num+1 as row_id   
FROM 
    Done,(select @row_num:=0)rownum
GROUP BY D; 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_2;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl_2
AS
SELECT * from tbl_1;   

SELECT tbl_2.D,tbl_1.D from tbl_1 
JOIN tbl_2 ON tbl_1.row_id=tbl_2.row_id+1
```